# SPFx package with app catalog metadata

Tags: spfx-webparts

Is it possible to create an SPFx package (.sppkg) that includes properties to populate the app catalog when it is uploaded?

I'd like to include the Icon URL, description, support URL, etc. Right now, the only way I can see is to manually populate these properties after I've uploaded the package file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ivan,

the metadata options are limited at the moment but-- according to the product group-- they are looking at improving package metadata with most likely after the [SPFx 1.14 version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.14) You can see the last publicly updated roadmap on the most recent community call at https://youtu.be/iMbQyxdPcSU.

Not the answer you were looking for, but I hope it helps?

Comment: Thanks for the update Hugo